# How can I convert GMT formatted Azure sign in logs to local time zone in Helsinki, Finland?

Tags: powershell, datetime, microsoft-graph-api

Hi I want to capture Azure sign in logs for users as per current time zone in Finland, Helsinki region.
Last sign-in: May 29, 2023, 9:57 AM

I am trying to fetch the same date and time as a result graph API query

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=signInActivity

The result is coming in GMT format

How can I get rid of the format and show the exact date and time format

The Last sign-in: May 29, 2023, 9:57 AM at Azure Portal captured
The result is coming in GMT format

Mon, 29 May 2023 06:57:54 GMT as a result of powershell query

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example of a timestamp as returned by the web-service call (which returns JSON format, I presume), what command you're using to parse the result in PowerShell, and whether you're using Windows PowerShell or PowerShell (Core) 7+.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that parses the date format and then convert it to what you want it to look.

```
function Convert-Date {
    param (
        [string]$InputDate,
        [string]$OutputFormat
    )
    $DateObject = [datetime]::ParseExact($InputDate, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", $null)
    $FormattedDate = $DateObject.ToString($OutputFormat)
    return $FormattedDate
}
```

```
$date = Convert-Date 'Mon, 29 May 2023 06:57:54 GMT' -OutputFormat 'ddMMyyyy'

$date
29052023
```